# Sample matrix indices in proportion to the matrix element values

Tags: matrix, probability-or-statistics

I have a 4 by 4 array which has a probability associated with each point.

```
{{0., 0., 0., 0.9}, 
{0., 0.05, 0., 0.}, 
{0., 0., 0., 0.}, 
{0., 0., 0.05, 0.}}
```

I want to sample the indices according to the probability/value at those indices in the matrix.

I should find point `{1,4}` many more times than I should `{4,3}` or `{2,2}`.

How can I sample the index where the matrix values correspond to the probability of finding that index?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Position` to find the non-zero probabilities:

```
m = {{0., 0., 0., 0.9}, {0., 0.05, 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.05, 0.}};
Position[m, _?Positive]
```

> `{{1, 4}, {2, 2}, {4, 3}}`

If you have large matrices, then you may be interested in using `SparseArray` to save memory and possibly also gain in performance:

```
sa = SparseArray[m];
sa["NonzeroPositions"]
```

> `{{1, 4}, {2, 2}, {4, 3}}`

Here is how to sample the indices in proportion to the corresponding matrix elements:

```
pos = Position[m, _?Positive];
values = Extract[m, pos];
RandomChoice[values -> pos, 10]
```

> `{{1, 4}, {1, 4}, {4, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {1,
>
>   4}, {1, 4}}`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to find the value according to the probability in the matrix. Using your method I can find the non-zero values, but this doesn't help the problem. I'll edit the question to make it clearer. I think I might have an idea...(based from this https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/23319-easy-question-with-probability)

Comment: @Tomi It was not clear from your original question, but now it is more clearly explained. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

### [WeightedData](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedData.html)

```
m = {{0., 0., 0., 0.9}, {0., 0.05, 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0.,  0.05, 0.}};

{positions, values} = {#["NonzeroPositions"], #["NonzeroValues"]} & @ SparseArray[m];
wd = WeightedData[positions, values];
```

**RandomVariate + EmpiricalDistribution**

You can use `EmpiricalDistribution` + `RandomVariate` to generate a random sample of  indices:

```
SeedRandom[777]
RandomVariate[EmpiricalDistribution[wd], 10]
```

> {{1, 4}, {2, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {4, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}}

```
SeedRandom[1]
sampleproportions = {#, Round[#2/1000000., .01]} & @@@ 
    Tally[RandomVariate[EmpiricalDistribution[wd], 1000000]]
```

> {{{1, 4}, 0.9}, {{4, 3}, 0.05}, {{2, 2}, 0.05}}

which is, up to ordering, the same as

```
Transpose @ {positions, values}
```

> {{{1, 4}, 0.9}, {{2, 2}, 0.05}, {{4, 3}, 0.05}}

**RandomChoice +  wd["EmpiricalPDF"]**

Alternatively, you can use  `arg = values -> positions` or `arg = Rule @@ Reverse @ wd["EmpiricalPDF"]` as the first argument of `RandomChoice` to get a list of random indices:

```
SeedRandom[777]
RandomChoice[arg, 10]
```

> {{1, 4}, {2, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {4, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}}

### MapIndexed

```
SeedRandom[777]
RandomChoice[Rule @@ Transpose[Join @@ MapIndexed[{##} &, m, {2}]], 10]
```

> {{1, 4}, {2, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {4, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}}

```
wd2 = WeightedData @@ Transpose[Join @@ MapIndexed[{#2, #} &, m, {2}]];

SeedRandom[777]
RandomVariate[EmpiricalDistribution @ wd2, 10]
```

> {{1, 4}, {2, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}, {4, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 4}}